# how to interchange the maximum and minimum members indices of a 2D array

Tags: c++, c, arrays, dev-c++

So this supposed to find the maximum value and the minimum value in a 2D array and exchange their positions, if the correspondence was 1234 of a 2x2 array it should be 4231.
Here's what I did:

```
    void interchange (int a[][n],int m) {
      int i,j;
      int cmin,cmax,rmin,rmax,temp;

      int max=a[0][0],min=a[0][0];

      for(i = 0; i < m; i++) {
         for(j = 0; j < n; j++) {
           if (a[i][j]<min) {
             rmin=i;
             cmin=j;
             min=a[i][j];
           } else if (a[i][j]>max) { 
             rmax=i;
             cmax=j;
             max=a[i][j];
           }

           temp=a[cmin][rmin];
           a[cmin][rmin]=a[cmax][rmax];
           a[cmax][rmax]=temp;
         }
     }
  }
```

I used another function to print the old and new array, but it always prints the old one, and when I tried to print within the interchange function to see what happened, it outputs a zero.

The if..if else statement part, I thought it would be more efficient this way:

```
  if (a[i][j]<min) {
    rmin = i;
    cmin = j;
    min = a[rmin][cmin];
  }
```

...but it still has the same problem. This is the whole code:

```
#include<iostream.h>

const int n = 2;
const int m = 2;

void read(int a [][n], int m);
void write(int a [][n], int m);
void interchange(int a [][n], int m);

main(){
    int a[n][m];
    read(a, m);
    write(a, m);
    interchange(a, m);
    write(a, m);
    return 0;
}

void read(int a [][n], int m){
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            cin >> a[i][j];
}

void write(int a [][n], int m){
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            cout << a[i][j] << "\t";
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void interchange(int a [][n], int m){
    int i, j;
    int cmin, cmax, rmin, rmax, temp;

    int max = a[0][0], min = a[0][0];

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            if (a[i][j] < min){
                rmin = i;
                cmin = j;
                min = a[rmin][cmin];
            }
            else if (a[i][j] > max){
                rmax = i;
                cmax = j;
                max = a[rmax][cmax];
            }
            temp = a[cmin][rmin];
            a[cmin][rmin] = a[cmax][rmax];
            a[cmax][rmax] = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Comment: You should probably show us your print function as well. Have you used a debugger to see what your array looks like at the end of the function?

Comment: i've added the detailed code in my question.

Comment: Minor stuff: 1) Suggest either passing both `m,n` to the  functions or pass neither and use global ones.  Now code is using one of each.  2) Pedantic functions would test for m and n > 0 before trying to access `a[0][0]`. 3) Could use `write(const int a [][n], int m)`

Answer (score 2):

There are quite few problems in your code.

1. Loop through entire array and then swap the members..So put swap code after two loops
2. First element itself might be minimum or maximum..so either rmin/cmin or rmax/cmax might never be set at all..so initialize them to 0
3. Use appropriate indices..dont mix column and row indexes

   ```
   void interchange (int a[][n],int m) {
       int i,j;
       int cmin=0,cmax=0,rmin=0,rmax=0,temp;
       int max=a[0][0],min=a[0][0];
       for(i = 0; i < m; i++) {
          for(j = 0; j < n; j++) {
              if (a[i][j]<min) {
                  rmin=i;
                  cmin=j;
                  min=a[i][j];
              }
              if (a[i][j]>max) {
                  rmax=i;
                  cmax=j;
                  max=a[i][j];
              }
           }
       }

       temp=a[rmin][cmin];
       a[rmin][cmin]=a[rmax][cmax];
       a[rmax][cmax]=temp;
   }
   ```